# Encoding a DVCPRO50

Tags: ffmpeg, video, encoding, dv

I'm attempting to encode a video into DVCPRO50 format.

I have found and read the documentation which suggests that FFmpeg should be capable of this, but I'm having trouble with the specific command needed to achieve the desired result. The documentation mentions using the `-target` option with `dv50` and also using `yuv422p` pixel format for DV50 across all standards.

However, I'd like to use an MXF container instead of MOV, and I'd also like to force Bottom Field First (BFF) instead of Top Field First (TFF).

Could anyone provide me with the correct command line options to achieve this?

This is the command i used :

ffmpeg -i Sony.mxf -codec:v dvvideo -s 720x576 -pix_fmt yuv422p -flags +ilme+ildct -top 0 -target pal-dv50 Sony21.mxf

when i check with Mediainfo this is what i get :

Format                                   : DV

Commercial name                          : DVCPRO

File size                                : 1.39 GiB

Duration                                 : 6 min 55 s

Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant

Overall bit rate                         : 28.8 Mb/s

Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS

Recorded date                            : 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000

FileExtension_Invalid                    : dv dif

Video
Format                                   : DV

Commercial name                          : DVCPRO

Duration                                 : 6 min 55 s

Bit rate mode                            : Constant

Bit rate                                 : 24.4 Mb/s

Width                                    : 720 pixels

Height                                   : 576 pixels

Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3

Frame rate mode                          : Constant

Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS

Standard                                 : PAL

Color space                              : YUV

Bit depth                                : 8 bits

Scan type                                : Interlaced

Scan order                               : Top Field First

Compression mode                         : Lossy

Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 2.357

Time code of first frame                 : 09:58:04:07

Time code source                         : Subcode time code

Stream size                              : 1.18 GiB (85%).

**I would like the Commercial name to be DVCPRO50**

**Bitrate to be 48.8MB/s**

**Scan order : Bottom Field First**

Thanks guys!